# Writing to redis using C++ using smallest possible bandwitdth

Tags: c++, c, redis

I wanted to write a ASCII string file to a remote redis server (this isnt really important, key point is redis writes strings) using the least amount of bandwidth possible. What is the best form of compression to do this? The file has rows like:

"Employee One - blah -blah" and I want to somehow compress each one, before a write since I have a severe bandwidth limitation.

A large file sample:

EMP1,500000,125670205,21.50,20.50

EMP2,215500,125670205,21.50,20.50

EMP3,251200,125670205,21.50,20.50

EMP4,234600,125670205,21.50,20.50

EMP5,735000,125670205,21.50,20.50

EMP6,134600,125670205,21.50,20.50

Its a CSV with string and numbers, I want to write it with the whole file and/or row by row.

Comment: A longer example of your file's contents would help us figure out a better way to compress it.

Comment: Edited to include file information

Comment: If you're writing batches of lines at a time, using gzip isn't too bad and you can easily make use of existing tools. If you're pushing individual lines, sending the numerical parts of the data in their binary forms is probably a good start.

Comment: Delta compression between the lines, followed by zipping would probably be quite good. That is, assuming fixed-width fields, subtract the binary representation of the first line from the binary representation of the second (and do the same for the next line, etc., always subtracting the line immediately above); this will yield lots of rows that contain mostly 0s (since much of the information is similar to the previous row's info), which is very compressible.